# Object Mapper giving Exception: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, objectmapper

I am consuming a spring boot application, On hitting the "/test/api" rest end point with a GET request from Postman, I am getting below error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "userName" (class
>   com.example.MyPojo), not marked as ignorable
>   (0 known properties: ])

The service I am trying to consume produces response in below format.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyResponse extends MyPojo {

    int responseCode;
    String responseMessage;
    List<MyPojo> output;
}
```

```
public class MyPojo{
}
```

```
public class User extends MyPojo {

    private String id;

    @NotBlank
    private String userName;

    private String companyId;
}
```

My Controller class looks like something below.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class SampleRestController {

    @GetMapping("/api")
    public MyResponse testApi(){

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String url="http://<Domain>:8085/users/active";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("header",headers);
        final ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange( url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class );

        MyResponse myResponse = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibility( PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        mapper.enable( DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
        try {
            myResponse = mapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), MyResponse.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myResponse;
    }

}
```

Please point out my mistake, I am not able to figure it out. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried putting @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) over MyPojo class, which resulted response like below.  ```{
    "responseCode": 200,
    "responseMessage": "Success",
    "output": [
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ]
}```  While debugging when I inspect the myResponse I see the values of MyPojo says "Class has no fields". How can I get User attributes mapped to MyPojo?

Comment: MyPojo is empty. How would you map something to a class without attributes?

Comment: @MarkD - To map user attribute you need to change List<MyPojo> output; to List<User> output; in MyResponse model as MyPojo is empty

Comment: Your user JSON string contains userName field but it cannot find it in MyPojo class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To map user attribute you need to have UserResponse-

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class UserResponse extends MyPojo {

    int responseCode;
    String responseMessage;
    List<User> output;
}
```

Similarly, for Product you'll need ProductResponse-

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProductResponse extends MyPojo {

    int responseCode;
    String responseMessage;
    List<Product> output;
}
```

also, define @Getter and @Setter annotation if not using currently.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class User extends MyPojo {

    private String id;

    @NotBlank
    private String userName;

    private String companyId;
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to keep  "MyResponse" flexible, as I want to use same class to responses for other Classes like "Product", "Contacts" etc. where all my pojo classes extends MyPojo.

Yes, I have defined Getter and Setter annotations for all Pojo classes.

Comment: To achieve this, you'll need to have different DTO's i.e. ProductResponse having List<Product>, ContactsResponse having List<Contact>, etc. Using Single MyResponse is not possible and not suggested. 
Alternatively, You can convert the response into JSON and use the output key to map to List<Product> or List<Contacts> as per your requirement. In this case, MyResponse is also not required. The first one i.e. using different DTO is preferred.

Comment: Thanks Akash and MarkD :) I used output key as you suggested and worked for me.